# Transfer matrix elements to another matrix's diagonal

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to do something similar to here (in Python):

[How to convert a column or row matrix to a diagonal matrix in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598572/how-to-convert-a-column-or-row-matrix-to-a-diagonal-matrix-in-python)

that is :

1) set all elements of matrix A onto the diagonal of matrix B (all other elements of B should be 0) and 2) after performing some operation on B, I want to recreate matrix A, so take the elements off B's diagonal , in the same order as was performed in the first step, and put them back in A.

Comment: So why another question? You need to further explain what you want , what you tried and why it didn't work for you.

Comment: I just said above, I tried the proposed answers there, but they do not seem to work for square matrices.

Comment: where did you say that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you not do just unravel your matrix onto the diagonal of another?

```
In [29]: import numpy as np

In [30]: a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

In [31]: b = np.diag(a.ravel())

In [32]: b
Out[32]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 4]])
```

Then, to go back:

```
In [33]: b.diagonal().reshape((2,2))
Out[33]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Comment: hmm, I did not know about ravel. But then how can you pack it back?